# How can I create an unknown number of child processes?

Tags: c, linux, fork

I need my code to be able to read n lines from stdin (each line will be a command from the Linux terminal), give it to a child process and execute it. Then when that child process ends, the program must read text again and execute another child process so that there are always n child processes running. I have tried in various ways but it always only reads one line even if I write several through stdin it executes only one child process and waits for more standard input. N must be between the values ​​1 and 8.

Standard input must be read in blocks of 16 bytes, and each command cannot be larger than 128 bytes.

This is the code I have:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 16

struct ordenes{
    int num;
    char *args[60];
};

typedef struct ordenes * ordenes;

void error(char * argv, int num_exit){
    fprintf(stderr,"Uso: %s [-p NUMPROC]\n",argv);
    fprintf(stderr,"Lee de la entrada estándar una sencuencia de líneas conteniendo órdenes para ser ejecutadas y lanza cada una de dichas órdenes en un proceso diferente.\n");
    fprintf(stderr,"-p NUMPROC     Número de procesos en ejecución de forma simultánea (1 <= NUMPROC <= 8)\n");
    exit(num_exit);
}

ordenes leer(){
    char * buf;
    if ((buf = (char *) malloc(BUF_SIZE * sizeof(char))) == NULL){
        perror("malloc()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    const char espacio[1] = " ";
    const char salto_linea[2] = "\n";
    char *token;
    ordenes orden = malloc(sizeof(orden));
    char *line = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*128);
    while((read(STDIN_FILENO,buf,BUF_SIZE))>0){
        strcpy(line,buf);
    }
    
    if(sizeof(line)>128){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: Tamaño de línea mayor que 128.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    orden->num=0;
    token = strtok(line, espacio);
    orden->args[orden->num] = token;
    while(token != NULL){
        token = strtok(NULL, espacio);
        if(token!=NULL) {
            orden->num+=1;
            orden->args[orden->num] = token;
        }
    }
    orden->num+=1;
    orden->args[orden->num] = NULL;
    return orden;
}

int ejecutar_proceso(ordenes orden){
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    switch(pid = fork()){
        case -1:
            perror("fork()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;
        case 0:
            execvp(orden->args[0],orden->args);
            fprintf(stderr,"execvp() failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;
        default:
            if(waitpid(pid,&status,0) == -1){
                perror("wait()");
                free(orden);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            free(orden);
            break;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    
    char *arg1;
    char *arg2;
    int opt;
    int num_procesos=1;
    int num=num_procesos;
    

    if(argc > 3){
        error(argv[0],EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while((opt = getopt(argc,argv,"p")) != -1){

        switch(opt){
            case 'p':
                if(argv[2]==NULL){
                    error(argv[0],EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                num_procesos = atoi(argv[2]);
                if(num_procesos < 1 || num_procesos > 8){
                    fprintf(stderr,"Error: el número de procesos en ejecución tiene que estar entre 1 y 8.");
                    error(argv[0],EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                break;
            default:
                num_procesos = 1;
                break;
        }

    }
    
    int i=0;
    while(i==0){
        if(num_procesos>0){
            ordenes orden = leer();
            num_procesos-=1;
            num_procesos += ejecutar_proceso(orden);
        }
    }

    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The Makefile that should be able to compile it is the following:

```
    CFLAGS=-Wall -ggdb3 -Werror -Wno-unused -std=c11 CC=gcc TARGETS=$(patsubst %.c,%,$(wildcard *.c))

all: $(TARGETS)

clean:
        -rm -rf $(TARGETS)

.PHONY: clean all
```

And for example it should be able to pass tests like: echo -e "ls -l\nls -l" | ./mycode -p 1

Answer (score 1):

In `ejecutar_proceso` the parent always calls `waitpid` immediately after `fork`, so it will not proceed until the child it just created has terminated.

If you want to immediately go on and create more processes, then *don't* call `waitpid` yet.  Create all `n` processes first.  Then enter a loop where you call `waitpid`, and each time it returns, call `fork()` to create a new process to replace the one that just exited.